# Subprocess doesn't show data from tcpdump in realtime. It shows with a pause about 10-20 seconds

Tags: python, pipe, subprocess, real-time

So i wanna get all data from `tcpdump` and add some logic in the future.
I haven't such problem yet with subprocess' pipes. 
I wrote code and ran `tcpdump` and `run.py` in parallel.

run.py:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# process = Popen(['/usr/bin/sudo', '/usr/sbin/tcpdump', '-i',  'wlan0'], bufsize=1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
process = Popen('sudo tcpdump -i wlan0', bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
while True:
    print(process.stdout.readline())
```

Output looks like this:
[image]
I tried different values for `bufsize` and other but behavior hasn't changed.
How can i get output as fast as tcpdump gets with `Subprocess.Popen`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's stdio buffering in tcpdump process.
By default  stdio sets the buffering mode to _IOFBF(full) on redirected streams.
Luckily tcpdump has `-l` option which switches the mode to line-buffered:

```
process = Popen('sudo tcpdump -l -i wlan0', bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, 
                shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Andrea's solution also works but mine would work on windows too.

Comment: Nice explanation. I know the reason now it's important. Thx. It  Works like a charm

Answer (score 2):

Try: sudo stdbuf -oL tcpdump -i wlan0

It works for me

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# process = Popen(['/usr/bin/sudo', '/usr/sbin/tcpdump', '-i',  'wlan0'], bufsize=1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
process = Popen('sudo stdbuf -oL tcpdump -i wlan0', bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
while True:
    print(process.stdout.readline())
```

Comment: You are welcome, I find it really useful especially managing vagrant box provisioning output. Thx to you and to robyschek for explanation.